# React Native Fetch Blob File Empty

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

We are having a problem with React Native Fetch Blob when a PDF is over 1mb in size. The file is being uploaded to Azure Blob Storage and works fine when the PDF is less than 1MB but as soon as the file is over 1MB the upload fails and the file in the container is empty.

We are using the module in an IOS React App but we also have a web app. When we upload the PDF via the web app  everything is fine so it seems that this is something specific to the mobile app.

Further testing shows that if we upload a PNG over 1MB it works, so this issue seems to be specific to PDFs.

Any suggestions on how we can diagnose or solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Michael, were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: If you guys are using a backend as in intermediary, maybe you have a file size limit?